# Call to undefined function http_send_file()

Tags: php, pecl

I have been trying to make  http_send_file() work for past two days. 
I managed to find all the libraries and installed pecl_http in my MAMP for mac 10.8
But it is still not working.

Appreciate any response on this.

Result of my script in command line
After sudo pecl install pecl_http

```
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/pecl_http-2.0.6
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
you should add "extension=raphf.so" to php.ini
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
you should add "extension=raphf.so" to php.ini
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
you should add "extension=propro.so" to php.ini
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
you should add "extension=raphf.so" to php.ini
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
you should add "extension=propro.so" to php.ini
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location 
you should add "extension=http.so" to php.ini
```

extension lines in my php.ini
    extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212  /"
    extension=mongo.so
    extension=raphf.so
    extension=propro.so
    extension=http.so

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes I did. But that dint solve the issue. So I did the following, sudo pecl uninstall pecl_http;                                     sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6;                                It Started working. I think php5.5.10 could not recognize pecl_http-2.0.6. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by using the following two commands.

sudo pecl uninstall pecl_http
sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6

I think php5.5.10 could not recognize pecl_http-2.0.6. That was the problem.